# disable uibutton from view controller controlling multiple skscenes

Tags: button, viewcontroller, skscene

I'm learning about view controllers and skscenes for a spritekit game and have a button in the view controller for an in app purchase.  I put it here and not programmatically in the skscene because I can drag and create outlets and actions that made the IAP setup easier.  However I need to disable this button during the skscene controlling the game to it isn't accidentally tapped. I can post code if need be but it's basically just a UIbutton outlet that I want to be able to edit another scene file, it should be enabled in the game over scene but disabled in the game scene.

Answer (score 0):

In general its not a good idea to use UIKit elements in SpriteKit games.
You should create all your buttons using SKSpriteNodes directly in the scene rather than using UIButtons in your game view controller. There is plenty tutorials to google on how to create buttons in SpriteKit.

Its a common thing people do

[How to fix the share button on SpriteKit Swift when Players plays the game again Share Button shows up on the game scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432232/how-to-fix-the-share-button-on-spritekit-swift-when-players-plays-the-game-again/39435294#39435294)

If you still want to use UIButton than I believe this is what you are looking for

```
someUIButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Just call it at the correct spot

Hope this helps